Joining two parts of a mesh
I have a mesh of a ring-like topology. Due to technical reasons, there is a cut in the ring, like at the top in the following picture. right and left side of the cut are not connected here; moving the edges would leave a gap in the ring. I want to remove this cut, such that the top part of the ring will be connected just like the bottom part. How can I do this?


Some more context: The cut is there because I'm importing my geometry from a .dxf file. In a next step, I extrude the mesh (and perform further manipulations), but I assume that it's easiest to remove the cut beforehand, which is why I'm asking about the planar case. The cut matters because I will render using a Grease Pencil with a Line Art modifier, which of course strokes the edges of the cut. That's what I need to avoid.
Here's an example file containing the geometry depicted above.



Make a plane.



Inset the face inwards ( I )



Delete the middle face ( X  ->  F )



In Blender mesh objects cannot have faces with holes in them. At least 1 edge needs to be connected to the hole, however in this particular case automatic triangulation of the resulting polygon that happens in order to display the geometry fails that you can see if you merge the vertices by distance:

So you need to have more geometry. The most logical geometry would avoid having concave n-gons that have problems with various algorithms in Blender(like triangulation or subdivision):

As long as you keep their vertices connected, you still have the option to only draw GP on the silhouette or contour of the object which you seem to do in your attached file anyway:

If you want to fix some geometry that you import from elsewhere, there is no real single workflow for everything. The solution is fixing it using modelling tools and techniques appropriate for each situation.
In the case of geometry in your shared file you can join some vertices with Connect Vertex Path(Vertex menu or  J ):

Then merge vertices by distance( M  ->  B ) to merge the ones you have at the connection. It's OK to do that with all geometry selected( A  to select all), and then dissolve the edge( Ctrl  +  X )(that's probably optional, nothing would happen if you left it, it's just not needed):

But you may encounter other types of situations and should probably get yourself familiar with at least basic modelling functionality. In this case, I would imagine most useful functions would probably be these:

Auto Merge functionality might be useful:

Understanding how transforms ( G ,  R ,  S ), transform orientations, transform pivot point and snapping works would be useful. Holding  Ctrl   down temporarily enables snapping while in transform operations.

This is just so you can manipulate the topology comfortably to get it to match the patterns you want(like making holes where they need to be and so that right parts are connected, maybe cleaning it up a bit if needed)

The final result is what I want (the extra edges are no problem), but I need to get there from what I have now. (My true geometry is much more complex and I don't want to re-draw it from scratch instead of just importing the pre-existing .dxf.) How can I do that?

I'll attempt to update the answer best I can.

Perfect, thanks a lot for the detailed answer!
